# About processing job name when executing Sagameker Processing job with step function and CloudWatch Events

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I'm currently considering a configuration where I have a statement from Step Functions that executes a Sagameker's Processing Job and call it in CloudWatch Events.

When Event was executed with the following statement, an error occurred because the maximum number of characters in ProcessingJobname was exceeded.
Execution of statement alone, not Event execution, works fine.

Could you please tell me how to avoid this?

> Value 'ID AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' at 'processingJobName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 63; Value

---------statement-------------------------------------

```
{
  "Comment": "This is your state machine",
  "StartAt": "SageMaker CreateProcessingJob",

  "States": {
    "SageMaker CreateProcessingJob": {

      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sagemaker:createProcessingJob.sync",
      "Parameters": {

        "AppSpecification": {

          "ImageUri": "354813040037.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.20.0-cpu-py3",
          "ContainerEntrypoint": [
            "python3",
            "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/transform.py"
          ]

        },

        "ProcessingResources": {
          "ClusterConfig": {
            "InstanceCount": 1,
            "InstanceType": "ml.t3.medium",
            "VolumeSizeInGB": 10
          }
        },
        "ProcessingInputs": [
          {
            "InputName": "input-1",
            "S3Input": {
              "S3Uri": "s3://AAAAA/step_test/test_data.csv",
              "LocalPath": "/opt/ml/processing/input",
              "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
              "S3InputMode": "File",
              "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
              "S3CompressionType": "None"
            }
          },
          {
            "InputName": "code",
            "S3Input": {
              "S3Uri": "s3://AAAAA/step_test/transform.py",
              "LocalPath": "/opt/ml/processing/input/code",
              "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
              "S3InputMode": "File",
              "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
              "S3CompressionType": "None"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ProcessingOutputConfig": {
          "Outputs": [
            {
              "OutputName": "train_data",
              "S3Output": {
                "S3Uri": "s3://AAAAA/step_test/train",
                "LocalPath": "/opt/ml/processing/output/train",
                "S3UploadMode": "EndOfJob"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "RoleArn":  "[role]",
        "ProcessingJobName.$": "$$.Execution.Name"  #<-I think that this is cause
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step Functions is designed to chain the transformation of an input JSON through all the steps [Input and Output Processing in Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html)

Despite not using this functionality (because you only want to execute a SageMaker job), you Step Functions workflow is actually receiving a JSON object from the EventBridge bus, for instance:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "277db284-fe99-dd73-8ce4-b7222d0350c5",
  "detail-type": "Step Functions Execution Status Change",
  "source": "aws.states",
  "account": "XXX",
  "time": "2021-10-29T08:13:50Z",
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:XXX:execution:XXX"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:XXX:execution:XXX",
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX",
    "name": "d0c93c04-df3b-e50f-2f5f-0e93f89a03a5",
    "status": "SUCCEEDED",
    "startDate": 1635495230428,
    "stopDate": 1635495230450,
    "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
    "inputDetails": {
        "included": true
    },
    "output": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
    "outputDetails": {
        "included": true
    }
  }
}
```

And you can refer any of this fields inside your Step Functions workflow definition. For instance you could use **id** field to create the SageMakerJob name:

```
"ProcessingJobName.$": "$.id"
```

or **detail.name** field:

```
"ProcessingJobName.$": "$.detail.name"
```

instead of using a context variable ($$).

This way, when defining the EventBridge rule that triggers the Step Functions workflow, you can apply an event transformation that calculates the desired value for the SageMakerJob name.